# Line 4: $data: ambiguous redirect when using passwordbox

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, dialog

I want to create a passwordbox using the dialog package.

```
#!/bin/bash
data=$(tempfile 2>/dev/null)
trap "rm -f $data" 0 1 2 5 15
dialog --title "Password" \
--clear \
--passwordbox "Enter your password" 10 30 2> $data

ret=$?

case $ret in
  0)
    echo "Password is $(cat $data)";;
  1)
    echo "Cancel pressed.";;
  255)
    [ -s $data ] &&  cat $data || echo "ESC pressed.";;
esac
```

However I get this error when I execute it:

```
line 4: $data: ambiguous redirect
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Line 10 is `case $ret in`. Is this your real script?

Comment: Yes. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Did you really get this error regarding `$data` at line 10, even though line 10 in what you posted isn't anywhere near the occurrences of `$data`? With the script you posted, the error should be at line 4.

Comment: Ähm. Well that's weird. You are right i get it at line 4 now. I have no idea why i got line 10 one time..

Comment: Is the accepted answer correct? it works, but got a downvote? THanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “ambiguous redirect” concerns the fragment `2>$data`. This indicates that the value of the variable `data` does not expand to exactly one word.

Given the way you set it, it's most likely that the value of `data` is empty because the `tempfile` command failed. You are, for some reason, hiding any error message emitted by `tempfile`. Remove the redirection:

```
data=$(tempfile)
```

The `tempfile` utility is a Debian utility, which you won't find outside Debian and derivatives such as Ubuntu and Linux Mint. It's likely that you're running this script on a system that doesn't have this utility. You can use the similar utility `mktemp` instead, which is widely available.

```
data=$(mktemp)
```

Furthermore, given that you're storing confidential data, you need to make sure that the temporary file won't be readable.

```
data=$(umask 077; mktemp)
```

This being said, creating a temporary file is more complex than necessary. Instead, instruct `dialog` to print the data to its standard output, and use a command substitution.

```
#!/bin/bash
password=$(dialog --title "Password" \
                  --clear \
                  --passwordbox "Enter your password" 10 30 \
                  --stdout)
ret=$?
…
```

Comment: Thank you so much for talking the time to explain everything. I am ver new to unix therefore it's a bit hard. You proofed me that i was not wrong about my concerns with just writing a password to a tempfile.

Answer (score 1):

Your **data** variable is null! you can see content of this variable with `echo $data`... it shows nothing!

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
data=/tmp/dialogsh-$$.$RANDOM; > $data
trap "rm -f $data" 0 1 2 5 15
dialog --title "Password" \
--clear \
--passwordbox "Enter your password" 10 30 2> "$data"

ret=$?

case $ret in
  0)
    echo "Password is $(cat $data)";;
  1)
    echo "Cancel pressed.";;
  255)
    [ -s $data ] &&  cat $data || echo "ESC pressed.";;
esac
```

Your input information will store in /tmp directory in the file which called **dialog.number.number**! You can change it in second line of the source.